# Display Google Map only if geocoding of an address is successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, vue.js

I am trying to write some Vue.js code that will only display a Google Map if geocoding the address is successful. However, I am having a bit of trouble with this.

Here's my Vue code so far:

```
const listingForm = new Vue({
  el: '#listing-multistep',
  data: {
    byAddress: true,
    displayMap: false,
    city: '',
    state: '',
    address: '',
    lat: '',
    lng: ''
  },
  methods: {
    updateLocation: function() {
      var fullAddress = this.address;
      if(this.city.length > 1) {
        fullAddress += (fullAddress.length > 1) ? `, ${this.city}` : this.city
      }
      if(this.state.length > 1) {
        fullAddress += (fullAddress.length > 1) ?  `, ${this.state}` : this.state
      }

      if (fullAddress === '') {
        this.lat = null;
        this.lng = null;
        this.displayMap = false
      } else {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder({types: ["geocode"]});
        geocoder.geocode({'address': fullAddress }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK'){
            this.lat = parseFloat(response[0].geometry.location.lat());
            this.lng = parseFloat(response[0].geometry.location.lng());

            this.displayMap = true;
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('location-map');
            console.log(mapDiv) <----- This is null, so map cannot be instantiated.

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
              zoom: 15,
              draggable: false,
              panControl: false,
              scrollwheel: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              fullscreenControl: false,
              center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
              disableDoubleClickZoom: true
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}
            });
            var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);

            map.setCenter(newLatLng);
            marker.setVisible(true);
            marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
          } else {
            console.log(`Status: ${status}`)
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And my template:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="listing-multistep">
  <strong><%= f.label :city %></strong><br>
  <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control', 'v-model': 'city', 'v-bind:readonly': '!byAddress', 'v-on:change': 'updateLocation' %>

  <strong><%= f.label :state %></strong><br>
  <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control', 'v-model': 'state', 'v-bind:readonly': '!byAddress', 'v-on:change': 'updateLocation' %>

  <strong><%= f.label :address %></strong><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control', 'v-model': 'address', 'v-bind:readonly': '!byAddress', 'v-on:change': 'updateLocation' %>

  <div v-if="displayMap">
    <div id="map-container">
      <div id='location-map'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="no-map" v-else>
    No map to display
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the map won't display upon changing the entries in the address fields. This is because `document.getElementById('location-map')` is null prior to being able to set `this.displayMap = true` which would reveal the appropriate div.

Is there any way I can display the div for `#location-map` and then reveal the Google Map upon successful geocoding? I think I'm quite close to a solution with the current code but struggling a bit to get it working properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about simple `if (...)` statement?

Comment: Yep that's already in the template. It should only display the div if displayMap is true.

Comment: You didn't get it. Just `if (displayMap) { logic here } else { other logic}`

Comment: The `updateLocation` function runs each time one of the input fields is changed (`'v-on:change': 'updateLocation'`). If I enter text into the address field, but `displayMap == false`, then the `updateLocation` function fails to initialize a map because the `div#location-map` will not be in the DOM. Even if I add `if (displayMap) { logic here } else { other logic }`, I will need a way to generate `div#location-map` prior to creating the Google Map, which depends on the existence of that div. I cannot think of a way of doing that with an `if` statement as the DOM would need to be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was right, but the scope of this line:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': fullAddress }, function(response, status) {
```

was not allowing `this.displayMap = true;` to bind properly.

I changed it to:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': fullAddress }, (response, status) => {
```

I also changed the template to use v-show instead of v-if so that the element stays in the DOM.

Works a charm now :)